# Date functions to pull day of the week

Tags: date

I'm trying to find a way to pull all records that don't have a date of the 1st or 15th of a month and so far no luck.  Can anyone help?

I tried the Extract, Parse, and Date_Trunc and I'm not getting the correct data back.

Comment: Can you post your attempt at solving the problem? Can you also indicate what approach you are taking (is this in a database or script)?

Comment: pulling records from a database? what database is it? is this a SQL related question? python? a text file? Excel? please give us more background because as it stands at the moment, there is no way we know what to propose.

Comment: (extract(day from m.mbr_expiration_dt))<>('1,01,15')

Comment: and date_trunc(m.mbr_expiration_dt, day)<>('1','01','15')

Answer (score 0):

As others have asked you before, it'd be helpful if you edited your question to include the language or database management system you're working with.

The way to retrieve records in a table whose date DAY is not 1 or 15 is pretty straightforward in most RDBMS. This is the way you can achieve it in MySQL:

```sql
CREATE TABLE authors (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(50),
  mbr_expiration_dt DATE
);

INSERT INTO authors (name, mbr_expiration_dt) VALUES
  ('Edgar Allan Poe', '2023-01-01'),
  ('Graham Greene', '2023-02-15'),
  ('Rudyard Kipling', '2023-03-10'),
  ('Arthur Conan Doyle', '2023-04-01'),
  ('Ray Bradbury', '2023-05-16');
```

```sql
SELECT *
FROM authors a
WHERE EXTRACT(DAY FROM a.mbr_expiration_dt) NOT IN (1, 15);
```